# Failed to build GNU toolchain and newlib 4.4 for ARM from scratch in X86 Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, cross-compilation, toolchain

I am working on an embedded RTOS on ARM, now I am going to build the GNU toolchain for the ARM in my X86 Linux host (ubuntu-20.04), so I did followings by referring to https://gnutoolchains.com/building/

1. Download binutils-2.42.tar.gz
2. Download gcc-11.3.0.tar.gz
3. Download newlib-4.4.0-20231231
4. Download mpc-1.0.3.tar.gz
5. Download mpfr-3.1.6.tar.bz2
6. Download gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2
7. Download gdb-14.1.tar.gz

Put and extract them into /home/t/testmnt/armtoolchain/, as follows,

```
@t-VirtualBox:~/testmnt/armtoolchain$ ls -l
total 442348
drwxrwx--- 20 t t      4096 3月  21 09:11 binutils-2.42
drwxrwx--- 13 t t      4096 3月  23 18:06 binutils-2.42-build
-rwxrwx---  1 t t  51892456 1月  29 23:22 binutils-2.42.tar.gz
drwxrwx--- 38 t t      4096 4月  21  2022 gcc-11.3.0
drwxrwx--- 16 t t      4096 3月  23 19:56 gcc-11.3.0-build
-rwxrwx---  1 t t 143527306 4月  21  2022 gcc-11.3.0.tar.gz
drwxrwxr-x 23 t t      4096 3月  22 12:47 gdb-14.1
drwxrwxr-x 17 t t      4096 3月  22 12:53 gdb-14.1-build
-rw-rw-r--  1 t t  41058403 12月  3 13:39 gdb-14.1.tar.gz
drwxrwx--- 16 t t      4096 3月  21 10:37 gmp-4.3.2
-rwxrwx---  1 t t   1897483 2月   1  2010 gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2
drwxrwx---  6 t t      4096 3月  21 10:42 mpc-1.0.3
-rwxrwx---  1 t t    669925 4月  28  2016 mpc-1.0.3.tar.gz
drwxrwx---  9 t t      4096 3月  21 10:46 mpfr-3.1.6
-rwxrwx---  1 t t   1287202 9月   7  2017 mpfr-3.1.6.tar.bz2
drwxrwx---  9 t t      4096 3月  22 08:05 newlib-4.4.0.20231231
drwxrwxr-x  4 t t      4096 3月  22 14:27 newlib-4.4.0.20231231-build
drwxrwx---  6 t t      4096 3月  23 18:07 out
```

I firstly configured and built gmp, mpc, and mpfr, and installed them into /usr/local/lib/

Then, I configured and built `binutils` as follows,

```
cd binutils-2.42-build/
../binutils-2.42/configure -target arm-test-eabi --prefix /home/t/testmnt/armtoolchain/out/
make install-strip
```

Then, I configured and built `gcc` as follows,

```
cd gcc-11.3.0-build/
../gcc-11.3.0/configure --target=arm-test-eabi --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix /home/t/testmnt/armtoolchain/out --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-plugins --disable-decimal-float --disable-libffi --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-nls --disable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-tls --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-newlib --with-headers=yes --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-multilib-list=aprofile,rmprofile --with-headers=/home/t/testmnt/armtoolchain/newlib-4.4.0.20231231/newlib/libc/include  --with-pkgversion='GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain 11.3.0'

make -j12
```

Then, I hit the following errors.

```
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/t/testmnt/armtoolchain/gcc-11.3.0-build/arm-test-eabi/arm/v5te/softfp/libgcc'
# If this is the top-level multilib, build all the other
# multilibs.
/home/t/testmnt/armtoolchain/gcc-11.3.0-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/t/testmnt/armtoolchain/gcc-11.3.0-build/./gcc/ -B/home/t/testmnt/armtoolchain/out/arm-test-eabi/bin/ -B/home/t/testmnt/armtoolchain/out/arm-test-eabi/lib/ -isystem /home/t/testmnt/armtoolchain/out/arm-test-eabi/include -isystem /home/t/testmnt/armtoolchain/out/arm-test-eabi/sys-include    -g -O2 -marm -march=armv5te+fp -mfloat-abi=softfp -O2  -g -O2 -DIN_GCC  -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE  -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition  -isystem ./include   -fno-inline -g -DIN_LIBGCC2 -fbuilding-libgcc -fno-stack-protector   -fno-inline -I. -I. -I../../../../.././gcc -I../../../../../../gcc-11.3.0/libgcc -I../../../../../../gcc-11.3.0/libgcc/. -I../../../../../../gcc-11.3.0/libgcc/../gcc -I../../../../../../gcc-11.3.0/libgcc/../include    -o emutls.o -MT emutls.o -MD -MP -MF emutls.dep -fexceptions -c ../../../../../../gcc-11.3.0/libgcc/emutls.c -fvisibility=hidden -DHIDE_EXPORTS
In file included from ../../../../../../gcc-11.3.0/libgcc/gthr.h:148,
                 from ../../../../../../gcc-11.3.0/libgcc/emutls.c:31:
./gthr-default.h:102:9: error: 'pthread_once' undeclared here (not in a function); did you mean 'pthread_once_t'?
  102 | __gthrw(pthread_once)
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
./gthr-default.h:90:19: note: in definition of macro '__gthrw2'
   90 |   static __typeof(type) name \
      |                   ^~~~
./gthr-default.h:102:1: note: in expansion of macro '__gthrw'
  102 | __gthrw(pthread_once)
      | ^~~~~~~
./gthr-default.h:103:9: error: 'pthread_getspecific' undeclared here (not in a function)
  103 | __gthrw(pthread_getspecific)
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./gthr-default.h:90:19: note: in definition of macro '__gthrw2'
   90 |   static __typeof(type) name \
      |                   ^~~~
./gthr-default.h:103:1: note: in expansion of macro '__gthrw'
  103 | __gthrw(pthread_getspecific)
      | ^~~~~~~
./gthr-default.h:104:9: error: 'pthread_setspecific' undeclared here (not in a function)
  104 | __gthrw(pthread_setspecific)
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./gthr-default.h:90:19: note: in definition of macro '__gthrw2'
   90 |   static __typeof(type) name \
      |                   ^~~~
./gthr-default.h:104:1: note: in expansion of macro '__gthrw'
  104 | __gthrw(pthread_setspecific)
      | ^~~~~~~
./gthr-default.h:106:9: error: 'pthread_create' undeclared here (not in a function); did you mean 'htab_create'?
  106 | __gthrw(pthread_create)
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./gthr-default.h:90:19: note: in definition of macro '__gthrw2'
   90 |   static __typeof(type) name \
      |                   ^~~~
./gthr-default.h:106:1: note: in expansion of macro '__gthrw'
  106 | __gthrw(pthread_create)
      | ^~~~~~~
./gthr-default.h:107:9: error: 'pthread_join' undeclared here (not in a function); did you mean 'pthread_kill'?
  107 | __gthrw(pthread_join)
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
.....
.....
```

I checked the `../newlib-4.4.0.20231231/newlib/libc/include/pthread.h`, it has following definitions,

```
254 /* Thread Creation, P1003.1c/Draft 10, p. 144 */
255 
256 int pthread_create (pthread_t *__pthread, const pthread_attr_t  *__attr,
257             void *(*__start_routine)(void *), void *__arg);
258 
259 /* Wait for Thread Termination, P1003.1c/Draft 10, p. 147 */
260 
261 int pthread_join (pthread_t __pthread, void **__value_ptr);
....
....
298 #define PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT _PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT
299 
300 int pthread_once (pthread_once_t *__once_control,
301               void (*__init_routine)(void));

....
....
308 /* Thread-Specific Data Management, P1003.1c/Draft 10, p. 165 */
309 
310 int pthread_setspecific (pthread_key_t __key, const void *__value);
311 void *  pthread_getspecific (pthread_key_t __key);
```

I googled and found similar issues, one pointed out there should be something wrong in the building system, but I don't know what problem it is.

So currently, building `gcc-11.3.0` is failed with `enable-threads=posix`, how to fix it and build a ARM GNU toolchain with newlib?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Thread support only makes sense if you have a target operating system capable of running threads; that’s not the case on a bare-metal system, so GCC configured in this way can’t support POSIX threads. Even with operating system support, you also need specific support in newlib and GCC; see [the `malloc` pool locking functions](https://www.sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#g_t_005f_005fmalloc_005flock) for example.

Building using the defaults (no `--enable-threads` option at all) should work just fine and pick appropriate settings.

Note that if GCC 9 and newlib 3.3 is good enough, you could save yourself some trouble by installing the `gcc-arm-none-eabi` package on Ubuntu 20.04. Later releases of Ubuntu have newer versions of GCC, but [newlib 4.4 isn’t available in Ubuntu yet](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/newlib) (it is available in Debian so it should be available in Ubuntu 24.10).

Comment: Stephen, the target OS is capable of running threads (the RTOS is using newlib and support basic pthread functions). And I tried building GCC with `--without-threads` and succeeded. I am not sure if gcc-arm-none-eabi can work with this RTOS (the vendor patched the newlib to make the RTOS work with newlib). Newlib 3.3 has a memory leakage in thread reentry, which is fixed in later version eg. newlib 4.4.

Comment: That does change things. Does the version of newlib you downloaded include the vendor patches?

Comment: The official newlib does NOT include vendor's patch, I patched it myself.